Is falsification of USPS tracking information (by a USPS employee) a crime?
The United States Postal Service (USPS) provides tracking information for parcels they are handling (e.g., the delivery of an item purchased from Amazon.com). The tracking information shows how the parcel travels through the USPS system, with each update usually having a status message, a location, and a timestamp. The last couple of steps of this process are usually "out for delivery" and an update that indicates how/where the delivery occurred (e.g., "in mail box" or "on front porch"). If delivery cannot be completed, another item is added to the tracking information to indicate this event and information on why this event occurred.
If the USPS employee intentionally creates false tracking updates, is this a crime that is subject to action from the USPS OIG (or another law enforcement agency)?
For example, if the employee simply cannot be bothered to deliver the parcel, falsely indicates that the parcel went "out for delivery" but "unable to deliver," while in fact the parcel never left the USPS facility. And when the customer subsequently is forced to pick up the parcel at the USPS facility, the tracking information indicates that the parcel was "delivered in the mail box."
USPS publishes this explanation of their tracking: https://faq.usps.com/s/article/USPS-Tracking-The-Basics
USPS has an additional "Tracking Plus" product described here: https://faq.usps.com/s/article/USPS-Tracking-Plus-The-Basics

By purchasing this service, you will have access to your online
tracking history for up to ten years for Domestic products and seven
years for International products. Along with the extended access, your
USPS Tracking Plus® Statement may be used as:

USPS evidence of delivery to resolve disputes and claims
Critical
evidence of mailing and or delivery / delivery attempt for legal and
court proceedings
Official authentic source of data that legal and
financial sources may accept


The USPS Office of the Inspector General is described here: https://www.uspsoig.gov/investigative-work and includes this list of crimes:

General crimes include:

Postal Service employees’ misuse of USPS computers,
Destruction or
theft of USPS property,
Falsification of official documents and
forgery,
Theft of funds,
Abuse of authority,
Sabotage of operations,
Narcotics use or sale of drugs while on duty, and
Alcohol abuse.


If such actions are subject to OIG (or other agency) enforcement, can either party (sender or receiver) initiate a complaint? Is purchase of the Tracking Plus product a prerequisite in any way?

The system is automated.

FWIW, the U.S. Postal Inspection Service (one of the few without its own TV show) and FBI are both law enforcement agencies with authority to investigation USPS related crimes. The OIG is a watchdog agency without law enforcement authority. And, anyone can complain about a crime to a law enforcement agency (even if they aren't personally affected by it and didn't purchase a service). The title question is interesting and I don't know the answer to it. It can, of course, easily be tricked contrary to the comment of @Tak, for example, by scanning a package as delivered when it isn't delivered.

USPS OIG definitely knows about this.

@ohwilleke That's not correct. The OIG is the correct office to deal with this, not USPIS. Like USPIS, OIG has LEO authority. The difference is USPIS deals with external matters, OIG deals with internal issues.

@user71659 O.K. I didn't know that. Thanks for the clarification.

Intentionally not delivering my mail should be “Sabotage of operations”, at a very low level obviously if it’s just one package.
